# Dividing the whole into a minimal amount of parts to equally distribute it between different groups.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

**Suppose** we have a finite amount of numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ ($x_i\in\mathbb{N}$) and an object that should be divided into parts in such a way that it can be without further dividing distributed in $x_i$ equal piles for any $1\leq i\leq n$.

**The question is** what is the *minimal* amount of parts for some $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ that would allow us to do that?

**Example:** we have a cake and expect some friends, but we don't know for sure how many of them are coming. But somehow we know, that the total amount of people will be either 5 or 6 $(x_1 = 5, x_2 = 6)$. So we divide a cake beforehand into $5\times 6 = 30$ parts, and so in each scenario we can just give the guest his share of the cake.

**Optimization.** Of course, 30 parts is too many. In the example above we could just divide the cake into 5 parts, then ignore it and divide the cake (like it was whole) into 6 parts. First we do 4 cuts, second we do 5 cuts; they don't coincide because 5 and 6 are coprimes. Total 9 cuts gives us 10 pieces. So instead of cutting the cake in 30 pieces, we can only cut it in 10. And that is the minimum here.

**Simple case.** Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two coprime numbers. Then, using the same argumentation as above with the case $x_1=5, x_2=6$, we can note that the minimal amount of parts is $(x_1-1)+(x_2-1)+1$ which is equal to $x_1+x_2-1$.

**Generalization.** First I thought that for $n$ coprime numbers the solution is simple and beautiful:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-1) + 1
$$
But this formula is **wrong** for $n>2$ as shows the following counterexample.

**Counterexample.** For $x_1=3, x_2 = 4, x_3 = 5$ the formula gives the answer 10. But that's not the minimum, as we can divide at least in nine portions:
$$
\frac{1}{60} + \frac{2}{60} + \frac{4}{60} + \frac{5}{60} + \frac{7}{60} + \frac{8}{60} + \frac{10}{60} + \frac{11}{60} + \frac{12}{60} = 1
$$ 
so we can split it equally in 3 pieces:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{60} + \frac{2}{60} +  \frac{7}{60} + \frac{10}{60}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{60} + \frac{5}{60} +\frac{11}{60}\right) + \left(\frac{8}{60} + \frac{12}{60}\right) = 1
$$ 
in 4 pieces:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{60} + \frac{2}{60} +  \frac{12}{60}
\right) + \left(\frac{4}{60} +\frac{11}{60}\right) + \left(\frac{5}{60} + \frac{10}{60}\right) + \left(\frac{7}{60} + \frac{8}{60}\right) = 1
$$ 
in 5 pieces:
$$
\frac{12}{60}+\left(\frac{1}{60} +  \frac{11}{60}
\right) + \left(\frac{2}{60} +\frac{10}{60}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{60} + \frac{8}{60}\right) + \left(\frac{5}{60} + \frac{7}{60}\right) = 1
$$

**To sum up,** the posed question has an evident answer in the case $n=1,2$, but in the case $n=3$ (and higher) I didn't discover any pattern.

**[Edit] Related Topics:**

[Minimum Cake Cutting for a Party](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383406/minimum-cake-cutting-for-a-party)

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/nine-gangsters-and-a-gold-bar

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214477/minimal-possible-cardinality-of-a-a-1-a-k-distributable-multiset

Comment: How did you discover this counterexample?

Comment: Also, in your example with 5 and 6 people you say you make 4 cuts and then separately 5 cuts for a total of 9. But you could align the first cut in each set. So you could make 4 cuts (for 5 people) and then 4 more cuts (reusing one of the existing cuts) for 6 people. Thus a total of only 8 cuts is required in this case. Am I right?

Comment: When you write, in the "simple case", that the answer "seems to be" $x_1+x_2-1$, do you mean you can prove it's at least that big? or do you mean you can prove it's at least that small? or what?

Comment: @rywit, I think we're trying to minimize the number of pieces, rather than the number of physical cuts.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, at least that small (you can make it as big as you want by dividing into $kx_1x_2$ parts with any positive integer $k$). In order to divide into $x_1$ parts we do $x_1 - 1$ cuts. To divide into $x_2$ parts we do $x_2-1$ cuts. Number of pieces is the number of cuts plus 1, so we have $(x_1 - 1)+(x_2-1)+1 = x_1 +x_2-1$. Geometrical point of view shows that this is minimum, but that is more intuitive approach than a strict proof; that's why I wrote "seems to be".

Comment: @rywit, about the counterexample. Dividing into 3, 4 and 5 part using the formula in the question (let's call it the naive formula), can be graphically presented like this:
[naive dividing](http://s24.postimg.org/g6ao4rzyt/gold3_4_5.jpg).
When we divide the object into 5 parts and then into 6, it can be pictured like this (numbers are sizes of pieses in one-sixtieth portions):
[first two series of cuts](http://s24.postimg.org/qrujgs6ad/gold3_4_5_2.jpg).
We cannot assemble any one-third parts using this pieses.

Comment: @rywit, but if we shift a little the second series of cuts like this ([dividing with shift](http://s24.postimg.org/gx3eak2c5/gold3_4_5_3.jpg)), we will use one additional cut but at the same time we will be able to assemble one-third parts and no more cuts will be needed.

Comment: OK, so for $n$ coprime numbers, we can always do it with $1+\sum(x_i-1)$ pieces, and the question is, under what circumstances can we do it with fewer, and how many fewer. So I wonder whether the $3,4,5$ construction generalizes to, say, $3,3k+1,3k+2$, or to $2k-1,2k,2k+1$, or some other infinite family of examples.

Comment: Note that the same question has been asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383406/minimum-cake-cutting-for-a-party